# Выбор элементов с проверкой их родителей

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

Нужно выбрать те `span` на странице, которые не являются потомками заголовков (`h1` - `h6`). Есть много  селекторов для потомков, но вот селектора, который бы проверял принадлежность родителю, я, увы, не нашел.

Пример:

```
<span>one</span>
<h2>
    <span>HEY</span>
</h2>
<span>two</span>
<h3>
    <span>HEY2</span>
</h3>
<span>three</span>
```

Нужно выбрать `span`'ы за исключением тех, что в `h2` и `h3`.

Comment: Согласен, мало информации дал
допустим у меня есть:




`<span>one</span>
<h2><span>HEY</span></h2>
<span>two</span>
<h3><span>HEY2</span></h3>
<span/>thre</span>`




нужно выбрать все спан, кроме того, который в h2 и h3

Comment: да, h1-h6 и jQuery в пролете

Comment: А xpath ? )  всего-то  `//span[..[contains(., 'h')]]`

Comment: можнт можно как-то через выборку эл-ов, то есть getElementById или querySelectorAll, только вот какие селекторы испольбзовать?

Comment: @Анатолий можно-можно, но с jQuery код был бы куда короче. Сейчас набросаю вариант (без jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Выбираем все `<span>` на странице.
- Для каждого пробегаемся по всем его родителям вплоть до `document` (можно было и только до `<body>`).
- Проверяем имя тега каждого родителя. Если оно входит в `<h0>` - `<h9>`, то отбрасываем этот `<span>`.
- Все оставшиеся `<span>` считаются результатом.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDomReady);

function onDomReady() {
    var allSpans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    var resultSpans = [];
    var regExp = /^H\d$/i;
    for (var i = 0; i < allSpans.length; i++) {
        var parent = allSpans[i].parentNode;
        while (parent != document) {
            if (regExp.test(parent.tagName)) {
                break;
            }
            parent = parent.parentNode;
        }
        if (parent == document) {
            resultSpans.push(allSpans[i]);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < resultSpans.length; i++) {
        resultSpans[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
};
```

```html
<span>not in hX</span> 
<h2>
    <span>simple</span>
</h2> 
<div>
    <span>not in hX, but in div</span>
</div> 
<div>
    <h5>
        <div>
            <span>deep</span>
        </div>
    </h5>
</div>
```

То же самое с jQuery (если кому-то понадобится):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var headers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        headers.push('h' + i);
    }
    var headersSelector = headers.join(',');
    var $resultSpans = $('span').filter(function() {
        return $(this).parents(headersSelector).length == 0;
    });
    $resultSpans.css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<span>not in hX</span> 
<h2>
    <span>simple</span>
</h2> 
<div>
    <span>not in hX</span>
</div> 
<div>
    <h5>
        <div>
            <span>deep</span>
        </div>
    </h5>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> да, h1-h6 и jQuery в пролете

Вот:

```js
$('span:not(:header > span)').html('hi there!');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>one</span>
<h2>
    <span>HEY</span>
</h2>
<span>two</span>
<h3>
    <span>HEY2</span>
</h3>
<span>three</span>
```

Но самым эффективным мне представляется простой обход в глубину:

```js
var stack = [$('body')[0]];
var elements = [];
while (stack.length) {
    var current = stack.pop();
    if (current.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'span')
        elements.push(current);
    for (var i = 0; i < current.childNodes.length; ++i)
        if (!current.childNodes[i].nodeName.match(/[hH]\d/))
            stack.push(current.childNodes[i]);
}

$(elements).html('Hi there!');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>one</span>
<h2>
    <span>HEY</span>
</h2>
<span>two</span>
<h3>
    <span>HEY2</span>
</h3>
<span>three</span>
```